# Validate Service Account Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to write a Powershell script that will validate a large number of service accounts that was provided to me by my AD team.  Not that I don't trust them but I want to cycle thru each domain username and password to see if it logs in or fails.  I am looking for some suggestions so far my attempts have failed (see post http://tjo.me/fKtvPM).

Thanks

P.S. I don't have access to AD so I have to try to login using the credentials to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really hacky (ugly for least-privileged model), but if you know that all of the service accounts have access to a particular program / file, you can try to start a process using their credentials.

```
$cred = get-credential # however you're getting the info from AD team, pass it hear to get-credential
start-process powershell -argumentlist "-command","exit" -cred (get-credential)
$? # if $true, process started (and exited) successfully, else failed (either bad creds or account can't access powershell.exe
```

Unfortunately, since you can't query AD directly, I think any solution is going to be a bit of a hack, since by definition you're going to have to simulate logging in as the user account.

Comment: This works but it is not as robust as I was hoping for.  I also need to loop thru a whole bunch of accounts.